# Can i make pageview indicator(the dot) view.GONE on default and VISIBLE on hover

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been working on a project. On the Home screen there is  small widescreen banner which have dots on it. After a while i just realize , its somehow covering words on the banner(imageView which have sentences on the bottom part) . Now, i'm wondering if i could make it only visible on hover / on touch(when the user is sliding the banner) and invisible while idle? is it possible?

Comment: You can do it most likely. I guess you are using a ViewPager, right?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right U need a pager for this target.
what is a pager?
Screen slides are transitions between one entire screen to another and are common with UIs like setup wizards or slideshows.
for more information you can see .
Slide Between Fragments with ViewPager
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

**this code help you to have better view to pager.**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Rivadeh on 2/9/2017.
 */
//Extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    //integer to count number of tabs
    int tabCount;

    //Constructor to the class 
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    //Overriding method getItem
//press ctrl O
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs 
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Override method getCount to get the number of tabs 
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

Good luck